# Error on my mysql query string

Tags: mysql

I got an error like this "Additional information: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near " when i running my code.Iam using webapi

```
string query = "SELECT `theatredetails`.*,`location`.`LocationName,`moviemaster`.`MovieMasterId`,`moviemaster`.`MovieName`,`moviemaster`.`Image` FROM `theatredetails` INNER JOIN `location` ON `theatredetails`.`LocationId`=`location`.`LocationId` INNER JOIN `moviemaster` ON `moviemaster`.`TheatreDetailsId`=`theatredetails`.`TheatreDetailsId`";
```

Iam using 3 inner joins,is there any error on my query?

Comment: You should format the query so it is possible to read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot a backtick

```
`location`.`LocationName
                        ^---here
```